# Undefined method error but only in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing

The test below generates the error message

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `avatar?' for nil:NilClass
app/views/members/index.html.erb:25:in `block in _app_views_members_index_html_erb___1876261578458959373_9315040'
app/views/members/index.html.erb:22:in `_app_views_members_index_html_erb___1876261578458959373_9315040'
test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:50:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'
```

Yet in development it seems to work. The avatar shows if present. Anyone got an idea about the cause?

The test:

```
get users_path
assert_template 'users/index'
User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
  assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user)

get organizations_path
assert_template 'organizations/index'
Organization.paginate(page: 1).each do |organization|
  assert_select 'a[href=?]', organization_path(organization)
end

get members_path        # THIS IS LINE 50!!
assert_template 'members/index'
Member.paginate(page: 1).each do |member|
  assert_select 'a[href=?]', member_path(member)
end
```

Members index view includes:

```
<% @members.each do |member| %>    # THIS IS LINE 22!!
  <tr>
    <td>
      <% if member.organization.avatar? %>      # THIS IS LINE 25!!
        <%= link_to image_tag(member.organization.avatar.url, alt: "Profile"), member_path(member) %> <%= member.username %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to image_tag("profile.gif", alt: "Profile"), member_path(member) %> <%= member.username %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <td><%= member.fullname %></td>
    etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means you've tried to call `avatar?` on `nil`.

The most likely cause is you have a member without an organization in your fixtures so that `member.organization` evaluates to `nil`.

Comment: Thanks, indeed such a fixture had slipped through which solved this error message. A new error message however arised, for which I'll post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the question mark

```
a[href=?]
```

should be

```
a[href]
```

Comment: I don't think it should be a[href]. I have a[href=?] in all sorts of tests and these work. Also railstutorial.org includes it in all sorts of tests...

Comment: Yep, the `hef=?` is right. The question mark is the place holder for the substitution value which is the 2nd parameter to `assert_select`. i.e. it's checking that the `href` of the link is `organization_path(organization)`